# Laravel: Set/mock application time globally for development

Tags: laravel

On my application, users have lists of emails they can send to. Their accounts have settings for the time of day they want emails automatically sent and the timezone they're in.

I would like to test certain scenarios on when my queues are triggered since each user's send time may differ drastically.

I'd like to globally set a fake time with carbon.

In `public/index.php`, I tried to set:

```
$time = Carbon::create('2020-09-16 00:00:00');
        Carbon::setTestNow($time);
```

but pieces of my application are not affected.

Is there a global way to set a fake time?

---

**Original question below:**

On my application, users have lists of emails they can send to. Their accounts have settings for the time of day they want emails automatically sent and the timezone they're in.

I have a command that will trigger an event that sends email.

Inside the listener, the `handle` method looks like:

```
public function handle(ReviewRequested $event)
    {
        
        $time = Carbon::create(2020, 9, 15, 0);
        Carbon::setTestNow($time);  

        $reviewRequest = $event->reviewRequest;
        Log::info('email sending at ' . $reviewRequest->sent_at . ' and current time is ' . Carbon::now());
        Mail::to($reviewRequest->customer->email)
            ->later($reviewRequest->sent_at, new ReviewRequestMailer($reviewRequest));

    }
```

Note that I'm faking the time with Carbon and setting it to midnight. In this example, The emails should be sent at 9am. The logged info is as follows:

`local.INFO: email sending at 2020-09-15 09:00:00 and current time is 2020-09-15 00:00:00`

So the current time is 12AM and I'm queuing these up to get sent at 9AM.

As soon as I run `php artisan queue:work`, the pending jobs (emails) are immediately run and sent. Why is this happening? They should remain queued until 9AM.

Perhaps queuing is using system time and doesn't care about what I set in Carbon? How can I resolve this?

Edit: I forgot to mention that I'm using Redis

Answer (score 0):

Check what queue driver you're using in your `.env` file. `QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync` does not allow for any delaying (sync stands for synchronous).

The quickest way to fix this would be doing the following:

- change the driver to database `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database`
- clear the cached configuration `php artisan config:clear`
- publish the migration for the jobs table `php artisan queue:table`
- migrate this new table `php artisan migrate`

After following these steps, you can now have delayed execution in your queues when you run it with `php artisan queue:work`

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to mention that I'm using Redis

Comment: In that case, try moving the logic into a Job class. Make the Job just send the email and then dispatch it from the Command class with a delay. I think I ran into that situation once and it fixed it.

Comment: So a Job to that will queue emails? I'll try that out when I'm back at my computer. thanks

Comment: so I've found it to just be the fact that I'm not setting the time globally. The `later` method works if I set it relative to the actual time. i.e if it's 11:15AM and I set it to send at 11:16AM, the emails queue correctly, but don't send until 11:16.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Laravel Cron Job for this purpose. you should make a file in App/Console/Commands/YourCronJobFile.php

```
     <?php

     namespace App\Console\Commands;

     use App\TestingCron;
     use Illuminate\Console\Command;
     use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

     class TestingCronJob extends Command
   {
/**
 * The name and signature of the console command.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $signature = 'send:Mail';

/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'This command is use for test cron jobs.';

/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle()
{
    DB::table('testing_cron')->insert(['created_at' => now(),'updated_at' => now()]);
}
}
```

Then go to directory App/Console/Kernel.php

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Console;

 use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

 class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
/**
 * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $commands = [
    Commands\TestingCronJob::class
];

/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('send:Mail')->dailyAt('09:00');
}

/**
 * RegisterController the commands for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function commands()
{
    $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

    require base_path('routes/console.php');
}
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling

Comment: My cron job will have to run every minute and run a command that will run logic to see if it's time to queue emails for a user